# Encrypting and Decrypting storage file

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, encryption

I am storing all `CoreData` and `NSUserDefault` values in a programmatically created `cdb` store file and upload it to user's `iCloud` to backup his data. So, he can restore his data from any device.

Since that `cdb` store file includes some sensitive data and the file can be copied to computer from `iCloud` and can be opened with some sql browser, I want to somehow encrypt the file before backing up and decrypt while restoring. I was wondering is there any way or tool to do that.

Comment: Why don't you use any Encrypt/Decrypt algorithm like AES 128,256 etc. You can refer Apple Documentation on [Cryptography concepts in Depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/CryptographyConcepts/CryptographyConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011172-CH8-SW1) for more details

Comment: Many, just be sure to ask the user for the password to use

Comment: Is it possible to encrypt the file with AES @DipenPanchasara ?

Comment: Yes its possible with AES, but small files only large file will create memory issue in app, Why you want to encrypt/decrypt whole file instead a property of table? Better encrypt specific information in database entity rather encrypting everything which will reduce unnecessary operations, To add extra layer of security create file with password protection.

Comment: More on it, CoreData supports encryption with inbuilt capability, use `NSPersistentStoreFileProtectionKey` to encrypt file. Check more details on  [this blog for File Protection](https://nickharris.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/core-data-and-enterprise-iphone-applications-protecting-your-data/). check this [sample for coredata encryption using SQLCiper on github.](https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data)

Comment: I tried SQLCipher it is ruining my database and relations. Also tried the blogpost but not helping. Any idea how I can password protection to file stored in icloud?

Answer (score 0):

Try RNCryptor https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor

**Basic Password Usage**

**Swift**

```
// Encryption
let data: NSData = ...
let password = "Secret password"
let ciphertext = RNCryptor.encryptData(data, password: password)

// Decryption
do {
    let originalData = try RNCryptor.decryptData(ciphertext, password: password)
    // ...
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

**Obj-C**

```
// Encryption
NSData *data = ...
NSString *password = @"Secret password";
NSData *ciphertext = [RNCryptor encryptData:data password:password];

// Decryption
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *plaintext = [RNCryptor decryptData:ciphertext password:password error:&error];
if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR:%@", error);
    return
}
// ...
```

Comment: I guess this is not encrypting the file

Comment: inside the file, you will have data only!